# the boundary of a star shaped domain has a subset for which the elements stand at an obtuse angle on the outer normal vector

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to understand a section in (PUCCI, PATRIZIA, and JAMES SERRIN. “A General Variational Identity.” Indiana University Mathematics Journal, vol. 35, no. 3, 1986, pp. 681–703.):

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth, bounded, star shaped domain with respect to the origin and let $\nu(x)$ be the outer normal at $x\in\partial\Omega$. It is stated that this implies $x\cdot\nu(x)\geq0$ on $\partial\Omega$, and there even is a subset of $\partial\Omega$ of positive measure on which $x\cdot\nu(x)>0$.

I understand the first part but why is there is a subset on which $x\cdot\nu(x)>0$?

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is smooth (I'm assuming that means $\partial \Omega$ is also smooth), $\nu(x)$ will at least be continuous. But then $x \cdot \nu(x)$ will be a continuous function. It is a fact that if a continuous function is ever greater than $0$, then it is greater than $0$ on a set of positive measure.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins But why is there an $x$ such that $x\cdot\nu(x)>0$?

Comment: How smooth is smooth? If $\partial \Omega$ can be locally smoothly parametrized, then you could make an argument like this: let $x_0$ be the furthest point on $\partial \Omega$ from the origin. Calculate the derivative of $||x||$ in coordinates on the boundary. Argue that we must have $x_0 \cdot \nu(x_0) > 0$.

Comment: It also feels like it should be possible to argue that if $x \cdot \nu(x) = 0$ everywhere, then we're talking about a subset of a hyperplane through the origin (note that a hyperplane through the origin clearly has this property). Though this gets me thinking. In what way is a subset of a hyperplane through the origin not a smooth, bounded, star shaped domain with respect to the origin? Is that a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\partial \Omega$ can be described as a smooth surface. It follows that $\nu(x)$, the outward normal, is continuous. Thus $h(x) = x\cdot \nu(x)$ is a continuous function. If we have that $h(x_0) > 0$ at some point $x_0 \in \partial \Omega$, then, since $h$ is continuous, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $h(x) > 0$ for all $x \in \partial \Omega$ such that $d(x, x_0) < \epsilon$. This suffices to show that $x \cdot \nu(x) > 0$ on a subset of $\partial \Omega$ of positive measure.

All we have to do now is show that such an $x_0$ really does exist. Since we have already assumed $\partial \Omega$ is a smooth surface, there exists an open subset $U$ of $\partial \Omega$ not containing $0$ which can be described as the $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g(x) = 0$ for some smooth function $g : U \to \mathbb{R}$. The upshot of defining such a $g$ is that now we can write
$$
\nu= \frac{\nabla g}{|\nabla g|}
$$

We now try to find the critical points of $|x|^2$ on $U$. If there are no critical points, then $|x|^2 = \text{constant}$, i.e. $U$ is a subset of a sphere. As you can check, $x \cdot \nu(x) > 0$ on a sphere, so we are done. Suppose now there is a critical point $x_c \in \partial \Omega$. Then $x_c$ is a critical point of the function $C : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
C(x) = |x|^2 - \lambda g(x)
$$
for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (this is the method of Lagrange multipliers). We calculate
$$
\nabla C(x) = 2x - \lambda \nabla g(x)
$$
Thus, since $\nabla C(x_c) = 0$
$$
x_c = \frac{\lambda}{2} \nabla g(x_c)
$$
But now
$$
x_c \cdot \nu = \left( \frac{\lambda}{2} \nabla g\right) \cdot \left( \frac{\nabla g}{|\nabla g|}\right) = \frac{\lambda |\nabla g|}{2}
$$
We know that we must have $\lambda \geq 0$ since $x_c \cdot \nu \geq 0$. If $\lambda = 0$, then we must have $x_c = 0$, since the only critical point of $C(x) = |x|^2$ is $0$. But we already said that $U$ does not contain $0$. Thus, it must be the case that $\lambda > 0$. Therefore $x_c \cdot \nu > 0$, and we are done.

I have to confess this argument doesn't exactly seem airtight, but it's the best I could think of. Maybe someone else can identify some holes in it.